# How to make mouse scroll to scroll horizontally in swiftui?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I have a View built using SwiftUI that uses Scroll view horizontally.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
      // this should scroll horizontally when user uses the mouse scroller
      HStack {

      }
    }
}
```

Currently user can do that by pressing shift button and scroll but I want to get rid of shift button

Goal: Mouse scroller should scroll horizontally without using shift button

Comment: This is not true anymore since iOS 15.

Answer (score -2):

You can see a tutorial here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JjN2sRQXLc&t=1176s

With the final code here:

https://github.com/gahntpo/ItunesSearchApp/blob/main/ItunesSearchApp/view/album/SongsForAlbumListView.swift

In sum you will need a `ScrollViewReader` that gives you a closure with a `proxy` that could be called to `scrollTo` method.

You'll need to mart the `destinations` to `scrollTo` with an identifiable object or using `.id` modifier.

All explained in the video.

Comment: the video points out to an iOS app where as my question's goal is related to mouse scroller which means it is a macOS app

Comment: Should work the same. But I can tackle in the macOS as well and respond later. This "implicitly" is bad in questions... we not read as careful as other things... most likely we are at work and respond while looking for our own questions. Make explicit next time.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO, If there is relevant code in the link please include in the answer.